# Index data row in a pandas dataframe whose order is not naturally sorted

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe which are sampled from another one so its row order is not incremented one by one:

```
    col1   col2
14  info1  info2
25  info3  info3
46  info5  info6
```

And an index object:

```
Int64Index([   273,    447,   1073,   1079,   1416,   1757,   1786,   2072,
              2389,   2657,
            ...
            366433, 366457, 366472, 367458, 367971, 368195, 368505, 369282,
            369402, 371835],
           dtype='int64', length=737)
```

I need to select the rows according to the index object from the dataframe, however, it seems that `.loc` does not work as I expected because when I used `df.iloc[Int64Index]` there will be an out-of-bound error. And if I choose only one integer from the index object, say 273, I found what is selected is the No.273 row in the dataframe instead of the row with the order of 273.

Comment: Are you talking about `loc` or `iloc` here ? `loc` forces indexing and slicing using the explicitly defined index values, hence using `df.loc[273]` will give you the row of index named `273`. `iloc` uses implicit index i.e. the "ith" element independent of what you had put in index (e.g. "Paris, "London" , or even numbers : 273, 2, 4, ...). Your index seems whitespaced, if it does not matter to you, you can simply reset the index doing `df.reset_index(drop=True)` (`drop` if you want to delete the former  index column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there are whitespaces in your indexes. You can do this:

```
df.loc['   273']
```